# Is there a block explorer that shows raw blocks?

Tags: block-explorer

I search for a online block explorer that has a raw view for blocks.

Preferably in the getblocks.bin binary format as hex string.

It would also be great if it had testnet network.

A bonus would be if the explorer is open source somewhere.

Edit:

[For bitcoin its something like this](https://webbtc.com/block/000000000000000001f942eb4bfa0aeccb6a14c268f4c72d5fff17270da771b9)
In [json](https://webbtc.com/block/000000000000000001f942eb4bfa0aeccb6a14c268f4c72d5fff17270da771b9.json) and here in [hex](https://webbtc.com/block/000000000000000001f942eb4bfa0aeccb6a14c268f4c72d5fff17270da771b9.hex).

I am searching for the ["block_complete_entry"](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_blocksbin) data of a single block, there should be also pruned tx data in there.

`struct block_complete_entry
  {
    blobdata block;
    std::vector<blobdata> txs;
    BEGIN_KV_SERIALIZE_MAP()
      KV_SERIALIZE(block)
      KV_SERIALIZE(txs)
    END_KV_SERIALIZE_MAP()
  };`

Answer (score 0):

https://xmrchain.net (source: https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer).

Open source and has various methods to call. E.g.:

https://xmrchain.net/api/rawblock/1637504

Bonus, yes has testnet to.

Comment: I am searching for the "block_complete_entry" data of a block. there is also pruned tx in there.

Comment: Look at the source to xmrchain and modify to your needs if there isn't an existing method to get the data you're after.

Comment: block_complete_entry is not part of the block, it's a RPC comms structure. You want block in cryptonote_basic.h.

Comment: @user36303 what about the --enable-as-hex flag from the explorer? I think that is the data that I wanted.